# Python regular expressions ignoring commas in a long number

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to figure out how to ignore commas in a long number, some the numbers are in the 0's to 10 million so I need something that can capture numbers from 0 to 10,000,000 and ignore commas.  I am not sure how to go about this.   Thanks

```
#Here is the pattern that contains the information I am looking for
Median Sales Price\n$1,417,000

# here is my pattern 
median_sales_price = re.findall(r'\bMedian Sales Price\n\$(\d*\,\d*\,\d*)',data)
```

Comment: I might use this pattern `r'\bMedian Sales Price\n\$(\d+(?:,\d{3})*)'`. it copies leading digits followed by optional commas and triplets of digits. The `(?: . . .` part is a non capturing group used to group the comma and 3 digits.

Comment: This worked! Thank You @ChrisCharley

Answer (score 1):

You can't. *One* capture captures *one* continuous substring. Capture with commas, then filter the commas out later.

```
median_sales_price = [re.sub(',', '', price) for price in
    re.findall(r'\bMedian Sales Price\n\$([\d,]+)', data)]
```

Comment: this works for values in the millions but doesn't capture anything less than a million.  is there a methods for capturing all digits and commas then I can filter out commas afterwards? @Amadan

Comment: Sorry, copy-paste-itis... I'll fix.

Comment: second version doesn't return anything seems like it should be possible with look around but not sure to format it.